# How to resolve "type of defaults to 'int' "

Tags: c, warnings

I'm trying to make a program and execute it from command prompt, but I'm getting error which I don't understand. So, function `spoji_saberi` needs to find sum of integers if `-b` is written followed by integers, and return concatenated string when `-s` is typed followed by strings. I'm pretty sure that this code needs more debugging, but now I'm getting error which I have no idea how to get rid of:

`warning: type of 'sum' defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]`

`46 | int saberi(sum, b){`

`|     ^~~~~~`

`3_3.c:46:5: warning: type of 'b' defaults to 'int'`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void spoji_saberi(int argc, char *argv[], char* (*dodaj)(char*, char*), int (*saberi)(int, int)){
    char *rez = 0;
    int suma = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(argv[i++], "-b") == 0){
            do
            {
                suma = (*saberi)(suma, *argv[i]);
                i++;
            } while (strcmp(argv[i], "-s") != 0 || i < argc);
            printf("Suma je: %d.", suma);
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-s") == 0){
            do
            {
                rez = (*dodaj)(rez, argv[i]);
                i++;
            } while (strcmp(argv[i], "-b") != 0 || i < argc);
            printf("String je'%s'.", rez);
        }
    }
}

char* dodaj(char* rez, char* b){
    char *newstr;
    int str1length = 0;
    if (rez != NULL)
        str1length = strlen(rez);

    int len = strlen(b) + str1length;
    newstr = (char *)realloc(rez, len + 1);
    if(newstr == NULL){
        free(rez);
        return 0;
    }
    newstr[str1length] = 0;
    strcat(newstr, b);
    return newstr;
}

int saberi(sum, b){
    return sum + b;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    spoji_saberi(argc, argv, &dodaj, &saberi);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to specify the type for `sum` and `b` in your `saberi` function.

Comment: Oh, thanks man. Been typing whole day, nothing weird to make mistake like this. Now it's time to see why it doesn't work.